# Trouble parsing SQL data with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have, what I think, is a real head-scratcher.

I am accessing a database to get a list of accounts. Each account has an account_id and account_parent_id property (among several other properties). If the account is the child of another account, the account_parent_id has the account ID of the parent and if the account is a parent (or has no children), the account_parent_id is blank. There are only two levels, so if an account has one or more children, it will not have a parent.

I need the output to be the account number (if the account has no children) and the account number of the parent and all children (comma separated) if there are children. Here is the code I have:

```
$SQLServer = "<database fqdn>"
$SQLDBName = "<databaes name>"
$uid ="<username>"
$pwd = "<password>"
$SqlQuery = "SELECT * from <account table>"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
$SqlConnection.Open()

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

$data = $DataSet[0].Tables

$SqlConnection.Close()

Foreach ($row in $data) {
    Foreach ($account in $row) {
        If ($account.parent_account_id -eq $row.account_id) {
            $accts += $account.account_id
        }
        ElseIf ($account.parent_account_id -eq $account.account_id) {
            $accts = $account.account_id
        }
        Return $accts
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm not getting anything at all into $accts. What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: You have something weird with your naming. `$data = $DataSet[0].Tables` is either going to be a table, or several tables. Then doing `Foreach ($row in $data)` - are those Tables in a Table collection, or Rows in a Table? If they are rows, why are you doing `Foreach ($account in $row) {` ? Either way, how do you expect the `$account` and the `$row` to *both* have the properties of an account? And why are you using `Return` outside a function? And using `return` in the inner-loop of nested loops - that will quit instantly. And you never initialize `$accts`.

Comment: You could probably do it directly in SQL with something like `select account_id as id, (select group_concat(account_id) from Accounts where account_parent_id = id ) as children
 from Accounts where account_parent_id is null;` - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e02abc/1

Comment: According to your query `$data` should contain a single table. What do you get when you output `$data | Format-Table -AutoSize`? Also, I don't think the `foreach` loops are doing what you think they do. Please show your table structure and explain which values you want to match to which other values.

Comment: You're both correct, this is all kinds of messed up and for some reason, I can't seem to visualize the looping to get the data I need. @TessellatingHeckler $data is a DataTable and the way it is written, both $account and $row are DataRows. I thought about trying to do the query in SQL, but I have been asked to take the whole table. I think my boss wants to have the least possible reliance on our DBA (we aren't really SQL guys) for future comparisons. Also, we can ignore the Return. I stuck it in there last night, while I was fiddling.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The table looks like: account_id|owner_resource|account_name|parent_account_id. How do I compare all of the account IDs to the parent_account_ids, to get a list of related accounts?

Comment: `JOIN` the table with itself in your SQL query.

Comment: I can't even successfully identify rows with blank parent_account_id's. I can see that row.parent_account_id[0].GetType() is "DBNull" (because the first account has no parent), but the closest I can get is: Foreach ($row in $table) { If ($row.parent_account_id -eq '') { Write-Host "No parent" } }. If I run that, I get one output of "No parent" and the loop is done. If I replace the write-host command with "$row.account_id", then I get every single account ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we did end up updating the SQL query. The data type I was getting back was a DataTable. I took out a row and used a loop like the following, to get he data I needed:

```
foreach ($item in $tableRow) {
    $($item.account_ids)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve your desired result is to do the mapping in SQL:

```
$SqlQuery = @'
SELECT t1.account_id AS parent, t2.account_id AS child
FROM <account table> t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN <account table> t2
  ON t1.account_id = t2.parent_account_id
'@
```

Then you can extract the information you want via `Group-Object` and [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
$data | Group-Object parent |
    Select-Object @{n='Parent';e={$_.Name}},
                  @{n='Children';e={$_.Group.child -join ','}}
```

If you're stuck with PowerShell v2 or earlier you need to replace `$_.Group.child -join ','` with something like `($_.Group | Select-Object -Expand child) -join ','`.

Comment: with that SQL query, I only get one row in the table. The Parent column is blank and there are a bunch of account names in the Children column.

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be `t2.account_id`, not `t2.account_name`. For further help you need to show sample data.